# Creating an event listener for a random error

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, scripting, listener

How would i go about creating an event listener for an error that could randomly appear while my test script is running?

I've tried researching for it, but I have not found anything related to what i need/want.

Point me in the correct direction?

Comment: You should raise a bug in the product you're testing, and work on a clean branch, not try to work around the problem in your tests. That just complicates your tests, and conceals the problem rather than helping it get fixed.

Comment: Also, you haven't told anything about what you're testing, or what the error is.

Comment: @AndrewRegan I don't want to go around the bug. I want do an assert.fail(); when an error message randomly appears while i am testing.

Comment: I know this doesn't strictly answer your question, but Selenium isn't really for finding random problems, let along working around them. You should know what will happen and assert that it does. If there's a random bug it needs a software developer to find it.

Comment: @AndrewRegan Our system is set up to throw an error on screen any time a bug, error or whatever happens in the code. If there is an object reference error, an error message will appear in our system telling us. I'm not trying to work around thing, i explained that. I want an event listener to listen for when those types of error appear because they can appear anytime anything is clicked on or loaded.

Comment: What kind of error message on screen? Could you show us the screenshot?